# Trying to create a button in outlook 2010 that replys to highlighted email/open email w/ static text and cc's an email address

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2010

Everything seems to work except adding the email address to the cc.
The account I am testing with may be hidden from the GAL.

Also is there a way to add the User's display name to the body text i.e. Great Job (dynamic name i.e. Ted i.e. email sending i am replying to)! I loved your work . . .

Using windows 7 enterprise w/ outlook 2010 professional Plus 32bit and exchange 2010.

Thanks! Code below

```
Sub GoodJob()

Dim m As MailItem 'object/mail item iterator
Dim recip As Recipient 'object to represent recipient(s)
Dim reply As MailItem 'object which will represent the reply email

'Loop over each SELECTED item:
For Each m In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
If m.Class = olMail Then
Set reply = m.reply

'Adds a "direct replies to" address:
'Set recip = reply.ReplyRecipients.Add("g@g.com")
Set recip = reply.ReplyRecipients.Add("someperson@a.net")
recip.Type = olCC

'adds Subject "Great Job! I loved your work on this Project" to email
 reply.Subject = "Great Job ! I loved your work on this Project"

'Adds Body of text to email
reply.Body = "Your awesomeness has been shared with Driver X" & vbLf &   m.Body



reply.Save 'saves a draft copy to your SENT folder
reply.Send

End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is failing about adding the CC address? As for getting a dynamic username, you might want `Account.Username` or possibly `Environ("userdomain") & "\" & Environ("username")`

Comment: It does everything else subject = 100% from code
Body of email = 100% from code.

Comment: It does everything else subject = 100% from code
Body of email = 100% from code.
When I look at the sent email there is not email address in the CC part of the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ReplyRecipients in this case just Recipients.

```
Set recip = reply.Recipients.Add("someperson@a.net")
```

Comment: okay, but it's a reply? why wouldn't you use the replyrecipient?
that worked! now ... =( how about getting the display name of the email address i am replying to is that possible?

Comment: ReplyRecipeints are the recipients where the reply will be sent when the recipient of your original message replies to your message. If you want it to be different from the message sender (you).

Comment: Ah, gotcha sometimes it takes me 10 times going through the code book to understand stuff like that.